# What is this Z-Shaped Alumnium Under The Soffit?

Tags: soffit, aluminum, fascia

We have an Z-shaped aluminum(?) material nailed to the wood under the soffit around the entirety of the house. The material has a white finish on the front with a gold finish on the back of the material, with a faux wood pattern on the material.

We've visited all of the home improvement stores in the area and not only is there not a similar product available, no one even has an idea of what to call this piece.

Perhaps of note, this material seems to come in 8 foot sections and wraps the entire house.

[image]

Comment: Think it is just flat trim/flat flashing bent to shape. Put on to protect the wood and save painting of the wood every few years. Might have been made on site from thin metal with a break. Take out the two bends and your local stores should have rolls of it.

Comment: That is exactly what was suggested to me by an Pro Desk worker at Home Depot, however no one seems to have the "faux wood" style. What's more, it's wrapping the entire house, so I'm a bit surprised that it would be done manually in that quantity.

Comment: The installer may have come with a brake that forms the Z-flashing onsite—not hard to do it manually from the patterned flat stock.  You may need to contact roofing/siding/gutter contractors.  What happened to the missing piece?

Comment: We had 12/2 and 14/2 Type NM (Romex, and Pre-Romex) improperly run outside that was flagged on inspection. Had to remove the pieces to access the finishing nails being used as bootleg cable staples. Several foot of the flashing was damaged in the process. In our case the best best is to trim up the damaged area with tin snips, get creative with a mallet, and call it a day.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a generic aluminum Z-flashing, likely custom made for your house by or for the contractor who installed the soffit. Once everything is set up it takes only minutes to make 10 foot lengths of this in a shop equipped with a shear, brake, and bulk material in sheets or rolls.

I presume that you're also asking "how do I go about getting more of this stuff?" If you want raw material search online for "woodgrain finish aluminum trim coil." You'll find smooth-finish coil in stock in many home centers but woodgrain may take more work to find. It would be relatively easy to build a brake that would help you to DIY fabricate the flashing, but it would be somewhat difficult to get crisp, small-radius bends and nice straight shears/cuts with home-grade tools.

If you're going to look for a shop to make these for you the first step is to prepare a drawing. Measure the length of the two legs, the height of the vertical web, and measure or estimate the angle of the bends. There both around 90 degrees, but I would suggest to have them made a little less than 90. This will give you a little "spring" in the top bend so that, when you push the part upward it'll sit tightly against the soffit. The bottom bend being slightly less than 90 will help ensure that any water that gets behind the Z won't become trapped.

Call around to local sheet metal fabricators, building material suppliers (not home centers), and siding contractors. Explain that you're looking to have a few pieces of custom Z-flashing made from trim coil. If you've got the right place they'll ask you for a drawing and quantity of parts to be made, but if not, they may be able to refer you to a shop.

Comment: Do you possibly mean "more than 90" rather than "less than 90"?

Comment: @psmears Bending it less than 90º *from flat* will give an obtuse angle between the two planes that allows drainage.

Comment: @psmears Possibly - it depends on perspective! I'm working from the perspective of how much the bending leaf on the sheet metal brake is moved. A 0 degree bend involves no movement at all; the sheet stays flat. A 5 degree bend would still be mostly flat, somewhat like the creases that are put into flat duct work. A 180 degree bend would be like a flattened-out V. "Almost 90 degrees" here means bring it nearly to a right angle. In all cases the included angle, measured between the two legs, is 180 minus the bend angle.

Comment: @GregHill: Ah, gotcha, that makes sense! Might be worth clarifying in the answer which angle you mean, as it definitely had me confused...